# Show that $GHI$ is isosceles.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

[image]
I am not able to use the fact that the smaller circumference is a circumference, what difference does that make to the problem?  I've done many, many calculations, but without using this it's impossible to demonstrate the result, how to do it?

Let $R=GO$, $r$ radius of the smallest circle, $x=GH$ and $y$ the distance from O to the point of intersection of the vertical line with the diameter .

Tracing the right triangle inscribed to the semicircle, I used Pythagoras a few times and concluded some results, but that didn't lead anywhere because I don't know how to use that the smaller circle is an inscribed circle, the most promising one is:

$$x^2 = 2R(y+R)$$

Comment: Well, the point appears to be that the small circle is tangent...both to the big circle and to each of the two coordinate line indicated.  That's a lot of information.

Comment: yes, but how to relate to the requested triangle?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  You ask how the extra information matters, but you don't appear to have tried to use it.

Comment: okay, I'll edit.  I am trying this problem for more than a day.  I couldn't use the smallest circle, just set up systems of equations involving Pythagoras and figure out some things

Comment: hint:  the radius of the big circle which passes through the center of the circle intersects the small curve at the point of tangency with the big curve.  Deduce that the distance between the two centers is $R-r$ using, I hope, obvious notation.

Comment: using your tip and the equation that I put in my post the problem is solved.  I am very happy and thank you immensely.  But I still have a doubt, how can you make the previous statement? It is very powerful.

Comment: Good work!  To establish my hint, consider the  point of tangency between the two circles (call it $P$).  $P$ is on both circles, of course, and the two tangent vectors coincide.  But the perpendicular through $P$ must pass through both centers.

Comment: Note:  the site prefers questions to be answered so, if you are willing, you might post your solution below.  That will allow the question to be closed and it will allow users here to check your work.

Comment: In fact, I'm baffled as to why I hadn't seen this.  Thank you very much.  I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Since $P$ is a point of both circles, there is only one tangent vector in $P$, so the points $O, O_2$  and $P$ must be aligned.

As $OO_2 = R-r $, we apply Pythagoras in the triangle $OIO_2$ and conclude that:
$$(y+r)^2+r^2 = (R-r)^2 \Rightarrow r^2 +r(2y+2R)+ y^2 -R^2 =0 $$

Solving The equatioin in $r$,we find The positive solution :
$$r= -y-R+\sqrt{2R(R+y)}$$

On the other hand, see that:

$$cos(\alpha)=\frac{R+y}{x}=\frac{x}{2R} $$

Then, $x = \sqrt{2R(R+y)} $

Using the first result, we conclude that:

$$r = -y -R +x \Rightarrow x= r+y+R \Rightarrow GH=GI.$$